# Is it possible to style and/or change icons related to labels on Google's Static Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

I've been searching for a way to change and/or style icons that relate to labels in Google's Static Maps so I can make them look how I want while not removing them. For example, hospitals are represented with an "H" on a circular red background, while supermarkets come with a shopping cart on a circular blue background. Is there a way to style the background-color of the icon, for instance? As far as I understood they aren't markers, therefore API related to the marker object doesn't apply here. I have played around with the [styling wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) for the sake of simplicity and exploration of features just to find out that labels and their icons can either be entirely hidden or shown, but I couldn't work on the icons only.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the icon's color.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=AIzaSyAJgC8JQGRAm8g_ADA2RRQ8piV-zJwb78s&center=37.762691,-122.45859&zoom=19&format=png&maptype=roadmap&style=feature:poi.medical%7Celement:labels.icon%7Chue:0xff3b9a&size=480x360

Here's a documentation for styling Google Maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/styling

There's no way we can use our own icon for POIs, however, there's an alternative way using Custom Markers. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers

Comment: Thank you! I had already found out how, but forgot to come here and answer. :)